# Google Data Studio : how to obtain a SUM related to a COUNT_DISTINCT?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a dataset including 3 columns :

- ID transac (The unique ID of the transaction - Dimension)
- Source (The source of the transaction - Dimension)
- Amount € (The amount of the transaction - Stat)

[screenshot of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp6v3.png)

- To Count the number of transactions (for one or more sources), i use COUNT_DISTINCT function
- I want to make the sum of the transactions amounts (for one or more sources). But i don't want to additionate the amounts of the transactions with the same ID !

**Is there a way to do this calcul with a DataStudio function ?**

Thanks for your answers. :-)

EDIT : I saw that we could do this type of calculation via SQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58960009/sum-distinct-by-key-or-symmetric-aggregates-function-in-bigquery) and I would like to do this in DataStudio (so that I don't have to pre-calculate the amounts per source.)

Answer (score 1):

IMO, your dataset contains wrong data.  Each value should be relative only to that line, but this is not the case: if the total is =20, each line should describe the participation of that line to the total.  With 4 sources, each line should be =5 or something else that sums 20.

To solve it in DataStudio, you need something like [CALCULATE function in PowerBI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax), but currently DataStudio doesn't support this feature.

But there are some options to consider to repair your data:

- If you're sure there are always 4 sources, just create a new calculated field with the expression `Amount/4` and SUM it.  It is not an elegant solution, but it works.
- If your data source is Google Sheets, you can easily repair the data using formulas, like in this example:

  [image: Spreadsheet with new column]

  [Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EWw5jgagelcuJVH2D9t4i_RfNeYvVK8FaGWCtCB2Bwc/edit?usp=sharing)

  For this spreadsheet, I used this formula in *adjusted_amount* column: `=C2/COUNTIF(A:A,A2)`.  With this column in DataStudio, just use the usual SUM aggregation function to summarize it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already calculated the "adjusted_amount" in another column (for linear attribution).

But now I have to calculate the "contribution" for each source. The contribution consists in attributing the **total amount** of the transaction for each of the contributing sources. It is for this reason that I created this dataset where the total transaction amount is duplicated for each source.

I saw that we could do this type of calculation via SQL and I would like to do this in DataStudio so that I don't have to pre-calculate the amounts per sources.

Comment: The same case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58960009/sum-distinct-by-key-or-symmetric-aggregates-function-in-bigquery)

Comment: Actually, the calculation of contribution is supported by DataStudio, you don't need to summarize and replicate the number for each line to calculate it. Just select the field, and in "Comparison calculation" select the desired format. You can select, for example, "Percent of total" or "Difference from total", and DataStudio does the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :-). I don't understand everything ... My initial data source is the MCF Analytics report. In this report, there is the full conversion path in one row, example = for transac id 101, there is "google> facebook> bing> email" in the source column. I have divided this path to have **1 source per row**. I cannot have statistics by source if there are several sources in the same row ... But I will still try to look in the "comparison calculation", it is a good idea.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you show your real data source and what result you want to achieve.